# If content includes object in array then add it to new array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that checks the user's content to see if it matches with any items in the array. Currently, if it matches it automatically replaces the content with a link.

What I'm wanting to do is add an extra step where it asks the user "Would you like to replace this word with a link?".

If it's a match then I'm thinking of adding that match to a new array, and then displaying the array as a card with a "Accept" or "Reject" button. If they hit accept then it will add the link to the content.

The issue I'm facing with the current setup is I can't add anything to the new array in the function, I get the error infinite loop. Any suggestions would be great!

Here's the function code

```
const generateContent = (content) => {
    let final;
    if(extraLink == true && word.length > 1){
      final = content.replaceAll(word, '<a class="newLink"   href=' + link + '>' + word + '</a>');
    } else {
      final = internalLinks.reduce((a, b) => {
        var reg = new RegExp('('+b.name+')', 'gi');
        return a.replaceAll(reg, '<a class="newLink"  href=' + b.link + '>' + b.name + '</a>');;
      }, content);
    }
  return final;
  };
```

I've tried adding but no luck

```
setAllLinks([...allLinks, b.name]);
```

UPDATE
Here is the sandbox link to test how it currently functions. Instead of it automatically adding link, I want it to show a card to Accept or Reject (the base of that functions is "setAllLinks")
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-cache-gqvoxl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It would be easy if you can create a reproducible sample and add link, you can use codesandbox / stackblitz ... add code, save and share the link :)

Comment: I don't see how `generateContent()` could produce an infinite loop. Also, I guess the error is not "infinite loop", but something like too many rerenders from react? Like when you do an unconditional `setValue()` during the render cycle.

Comment: I have added a sandbox link to the file. Hope this helps explain the outcome better

Comment: @user16034511 I added an answer, Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by checking the matched words and then show the confirm dialog and based on the user action you can replace the word with a link.

Just for a demo purpose, I used default window [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) dialog but you can create your own custom dialog box and make the changes accordingly.

**Update :** As per the author comment, Updated the below code snippet.

One suggestion, Instead of checking the text field value on each and every keypress check it once user done with the typing. I am demoing using `onBlur()` event.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const searchArr = [{
  word: 'Beta',
  link: 'Beta link'
}, {
  word: 'profile',
  link: 'Profile link'
}, {
  word: 'company',
  link: 'Company link'
}];

function getInputValue(e) {
  const content = e.target.value;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = generateContent(content);
}

const generateContent = (content) => {
  searchArr.forEach(obj => {
    if (content.includes(obj.word)) {
      if (confirm(`Would you like to replace this word ${obj.word} with a link ?`)) {
        content = content.replaceAll(obj.word, `<a class="newLink" href=${obj.link}>${obj.word}</a>`);
      }
    }
  })
  return content;
};
```

```html
Enter Text Here : <input type="text" onBlur="getInputValue(event)"/>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This somewhat works but not fully.

1. Content is a text field and this function only works if I paste content into the text field. If I type it out it gives me the confirm window everytime I tap a key.
2. My question was how can I add it to a separate array, something like searchArr.push ?

Comment: @user16034511 I updated my answer as per the requirement but my suggestion would be that instead of checking the text field value on each and every keypress, check it once user done with the typing as it will help in increasing the user experience and performance as well. I am demoing using `onBlur()` event. Also, no need to push the find words in a separate array.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I've got it working from this